# Is there a way to change develop host from IIS to something else?

Tags: iis

I have one simple question: is there a way to change IIS to another hosting provider for development? Because from 2 days I have only problems with that and nothing more. Like i m looking for something that can let me debug app.

Comment: What kind of application are you working on? Without that it is impossible to have an answer.

Comment: I m working on .net core Rest api

Comment: Before you launch the debugger from within Visual Studio, you can change the debugging settings (IIS Express/IIS or simply Kestrel). Try that first.

Answer (score 0):

By default, VS will create two type debug profile.

Debug from IIS express or debug from Kestrel.

[image]

In debug property, you can find various kinds of launch operation for debugging.

[image]